# Integrate[Sqrt[(1 - Cos[t])/(Cos[a] - Cos[t])], {t, a, Pi}, Assumptions -> 0 < a < Pi] gives a Complex Expression rather than Pi

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

`Integrate[Sqrt[(1 - Cos[t])/(Cos[a] - Cos[t])], {t, a, Pi},   Assumptions -> 0 < a < Pi]` gives a Complex Expression rather than `Pi` which is what I expect.

The integral arises in the Tautochrone problem, i.e. this is the integral above the line "(2):" on the page https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cycloid_has_Tautochrone_Property

I assume the expression is Complex because Mathematica assumes the expression inside the Sqrt is negative at some points but I don't think that is true.

I understand that the integrand has a singularity at t = a making the denominator 0 but I was hoping Mathematica could do the Integration. It doesn't complain about the singularity.

I am using Mathematica 12.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assumptions are not always applied as constraints. (Took a bit extra massaging to get the result of `Integrate` into its fully simplified form under the assumptions.)

```
res = Integrate[Sqrt[(1 - Cos[t])/(Cos[a] - Cos[t])],
  {t, a, Pi}, 
  Assumptions -> 0 < a < Pi]
(*
-I (-1)^Floor[(π + Arg[-1 + Cos[a]])/(
  2 π)] (Log[2] + 2 Log[Cos[a/2]] - Log[-1 - Cos[a]])
*)

Assuming[0 < a < Pi,
 PiecewiseExpand[FullSimplify[res],
  Method -> {"ConditionSimplifier" -> 
    (Reduce[# && $Assumptions, ##2] &)}]
 ]

(*  Pi  *)
```

Comment: +1 Add the redundant assumption that `Cos[a] < 1`, i.e., `Assuming[0 < a < Pi && Cos[a] < 1, Integrate[Sqrt[(1 - Cos[t])/(Cos[a] - Cos[t])], {t, a, Pi}] // FullSimplify]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks. I thought of that (`Cos[a] < 1`), which appears in the output of `FullSimplify[]`; but I wanted to see if I could get Mathematica to deduce it. I don't know why it took such an effort to get it to do that. `Simplify[]` or `FullSimplify[]` (with the assumption `0 < a < Pi`) ought to be enough, imo.

Comment: I agree, that is why I refer to it as a **redundant** assumption.

Comment: @BobHanlon I noticed and understood "**redundant**". I was explaining why I didn't use `Cos[a] < 1`. I also realize it simplifies the code. Still, for whatever reason, I was stubbornly focused on taming Mma.

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Thanks Michael and Bob! This is a great site!

Comment: @BobHanlon, any idea why the Assuming requires a "// FullSimplify" but the following does not? Integrate[Sqrt[(1 - Cos[t])/(Cos[a] - Cos[t])], {t, a, Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> 0 < a < Pi && Cos[a] < 1]

Comment: @GeorgeColpitts - it doesn't. `Assuming[0 < a < Pi && Cos[a] < 1, 
 Integrate[Sqrt[(1 - Cos[t])/(Cos[a] - Cos[t])], {t, a, Pi}]]` evaluates to `Pi`  The `FullSimplify` was included before the additional assumption, and its need wasn't checked by me after the second assumption was added.

Comment: @BobHanlon, sorry my mistake. I thought I had seen the problem in my previous comment but I can't reproduce it now so I am obviously mistaken. Sorry about that.

Comment: I reported the need for a redundant constraint to Mathematica as it seems to me a bug. CASE:4969964. They said they would forward it to developers. I don't think I can file a bug as I have the home version of Mathematica.

Answer (score 4):

$a$ needs to be between 0 and `Pi/2` so that `Cos[a]` remain positive in order to simplify the sqrt which comes into play using the substitution made in the page.

Starting from

[image]

Then using Mathematica

```
Integrate[Sin[1/2*t]/Sqrt[Cos[1/2*a]^2 - Cos[1/2*t]^2], {t, a, Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> 0 < a < Pi/2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks Naseer but I wanted a solution for my original integral as I want Mathematica to do as much work as possible.